# Video editor w/ stabilization?

Tags: software-rec, video-editing

As I slowly migrate from Apple's Mac OS X to a Linux distribution, I try to find good replacements for Apple's iLife software suite. I particularly like the current iMovie's image stabilization feature, where at the cost of losing a bit of resolution, shaky footage can be stabilized so that you almost can't tell the camera was shaking.

Is there an open source Linux video editor that has a similar feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10725141/535203), you can use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) with [vid.stab](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab).

If your video is named `input.mp4` execute those 2 steps:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=10:accuracy=15:result="mytransforms.trf" -f null -
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="mytransforms.trf" -c:a copy out_stabilized.mp4
```

The first step is used to create the stabilization profile, and the final stabilized video will be created at `out_stabilized.mp4`.

For high quality output, use this second step in place of the previous one (thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20445691/535203)):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="mytransforms.trf" -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy out_stabilized.mp4
```

More information on the parameters can be found in the [vid.stab GitHub Project](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab).

Answer (score 4):

[Cinelerra](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcinelerra.org%2F&ei=Ti4uTce5JsL58Ab-r7SZCQ&usg=AFQjCNGYmiMt6AU8KsYjOSPu4B-fu7FbXw&sig2=6baBS4TaKXhbdkwY8__2kw) is the only tool I'm aware of that can do this in Linux. There is a [tutorial on just this topic](http://crazedmuleproductions.blogspot.com/2009/03/motion-stabilization-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out [MLT](http://www.mltframework.org/) and it's **[videostab2 filter](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/FilterVideostab2)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [AviSynth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avisynth), using a filter called *Deshaker* which is written for [VirtualDub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualdub), but also works with AviSynth.

It isn't specifically Linux , but both programs mentioned work quite well under `wine`, and are definitely Free and Open Source in spirit and are *GNU GPL'd*.  The developers just happened to start developing it Windows land, and it proved too difficult to port to *nix.

Avisynth is a media scripting language. If you are happy with scripting at the  coal-face, then AviSnth is awsome. If you want to point and click, it's not for you.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here are some pics (video actually) ..

- [Snowboard + DeShaker](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHmVjhz94aU)
- [VirtualDub Deshaker Demo 手ぶれ補正のデジタル処理2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qja7CJ8fkPk)
- [Extreme demo of De Shake & Virtual Dub HD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWOh1GAK2J4)